# Including the minelead API in my code and how to understand its syntax

Tags: api

I am trying to add the [Minelead API](https://minelead.io/docs/) to my code to allow myself to search and find out user emails from certain domains.

I am unable to find a list of syntax or an explanation of how to implement the API into my code.

I can include the API through script tags but aside from that I am completely lost, an answer or a good API tutorial would really help,thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Mohamed from the Minelead Developer Team

As for your request, I need to know what programming language you're using, and what you're trying to do exactly.

we have examples in the [documentation page](https://api.minelead.io/) of simple cURL requests.

Here's also a simple example in Python using the [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) module

```py
import requests as req

uri = "https://api.minelead.io/v1/search/?domain=example.com&key=yourApiKey"

response = req.get(uri)

print(response.json())
```